# Ctypes Offset Into A Buffer

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a string buffer: `b = create_string_buffer(numb)` where `numb` is a number of bytes.

In my wrapper I need to splice up this buffer. When calling a function that expects a `POINTER(c_char)` I can do: `myfunction(self, byref(b, offset))` but in a Structure:

```
 class mystruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("buf", POINTER(c_char))]
```

I am unable to do this, getting an argument type exception. So my question is: how can I assign `.buf` to be an offset into b. Direct assignment works so `.buf = b`, however this is unsuitable. (Python does not hold up to well against ~32,000 such buffers being created every second, hence my desire to use a single spliced buffer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctypes.cast`

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> b = ctypes.create_string_buffer(500)
>>> b[:6] = 'foobar'
>>> ctypes.cast(ctypes.byref(b, 4), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
<ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x100756e60>
>>> _.contents
c_char('a')
```